# autocomplete [displayWith] doesn't display name

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

I'm using autocomplete material for my project but I don't understand how to use [displayWith]. I try  some example but not display name in html, only id.

My html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="editClientForm">
  <input formControlName="city_id" id="city_id" matInput placeholder="Select City*" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto1"
    autoActiveFirstOption [formControl]="city">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFnCity">
    <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event, city.city_id, 'city_id')" *ngFor="let city of filteredOptionsCity | async"
      [value]="city.name">
      {{ city.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</form>
```

My ts component:

```
  cityid = 0;
  filteredOptionsCity: any;
  city: FormControl = new FormControl();
  editClientForm: FormGroup;
    this.editClientForm = this.fb.group({
      'city_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
         });
  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptionsCity = this.city.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this.filterCity(value))
    );
}

  populateForm() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.clientService.getClientById(params['id']).subscribe(
          client => {
            this.client = client;
            console.log(client)
            this.editClientForm.controls['city_id'].setValue(client.city);
            console.log(client.city);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
  // City
  filterCity(val: string): City[] {
    if (val) {
      let filterValue = val.toLowerCase();
      console.log(this.cityes)
      return this.cityes.filter(city => city.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue));
    }

    return this.cityes;
  }

  updateForm(ev: any, idd: any, componentid: any) {

    if (ev.isUserInput) {
      if (componentid === 'city_id') {
        this.cityid = idd;
        this.editClientForm['controls']['city_id'].setValue(ev.source.value);
      } else {
        console.log('test');
      }
    }
  }
```

My class Client:

```
export class Client {  
city: City[];}
```

My class City:

```
export class City {
  city_id: string;
  name: string; }
```

In html show me clity_id, I want city name.

I try to use this code, but nothing happends:

```
   getName(productid: string) {
      const [filteredProdG] = this.cityes.filter(pt => pt.city_id === productid);

   if (typeof filteredProdG !== 'undefined' && productid === filteredProdG.city_id) {
       return filteredProdG.name;
     } 
   }

1.   displayFnCity(city?: City): string {
         console.log(city ? city.name : undefined) //show undefined
     return city ? city.name : undefined;
      }
2.  displayFnCity(city) {
    console.log(city.name) //show undefined
    return city.name;
  }
```

3. If I try `[displayWith]="displayFn"` or `[displayWith]="displayFnCity"`   show in html only  id_city

Please any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The `[displayWith]` function will be passed the `[value]` object. Since in your case you used `[value]="city.name"` you don't need to use `[displayWith]` because by default the autocomplete will display whatever `[value]` is. Normally one would use `[displayWith]` when `[value]` is bound to an object that is not a human-recognizable string. For example if you used `[value]="city"`, then you would also want to use `[displayWith]="displayFnCity"` (your #1).

Comment: Replace
`<mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFnCity">`
with
`<mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete">`

Comment: Yes, but that I want is, how to show in my page client.name, not client_id.

Comment: You can't display Client when the option values are City.

Comment: Sorry, I  was wrong. How to show in my page city.name, not city_id.

Comment: Once again, based on the code you already have using `[value]="city.name"`, you only need to remove `[displayWith]="displayFnCity"`. So replace `<mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFnCity">` with `<mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete">`.

Comment: Please create a stickblitz example.

Comment: Please can you look this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html  In this exp. I want to show my country, like my name and email.

Comment: You do not have country defined anywhere. Do you mean state? Right now it works perfectly - select a state and it shows the state name. Please explain clearly what isn't working and what you want it to do.

Comment: I used populateForm() to populate my form, in this example, I populate only email and client_name, not name of city_id. That I want is to display automaticly and Florida, name of city ( city_id: '3',) for client MyName.